# How to access property after json parsing

Tags: node.js, json

could someone help me to find a way to access apple value?
I'm getting this info from the HTML website, then JSON.parsing it but can find a way to access it.
This is the code I made

```
var data = JSON.parse(body);
var applevalue = data.store.products.apple;

{"store":{"products":[{"apples":20}]}}
```

And I am getting

> Cannot read property 'products' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data.store.products is an array, you need to set the index in products to access apple.

You can do:

```
var data = JSON.parse(body);
var appleValue = data.store.products[0].apples;
```

Comment: thank you, could give me one more tip, how I can check if 
{"store":{}}
or 
{"store":{"products":[{"apples":20}]}} so when site is down aplication wont ask for information

Comment: You can check the array by the length if (data.store.products.length > 0) { do.anything } or the objects with if (data) { do.anything }

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code:

```
 var jsonData = JSON.parse('{"store":{"products":[{"apples":20}]}}');
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.store.products.length; i++) {
        var product = jsonData.store.products[i];
        console.log(product.apples);
    }
```

Comment: thank you, could give me one more tip, how I can check if 
{"store":{}}
or 
{"store":{"products":[{"apples":20}]}} so when site is down aplication wont ask for information

Comment: i didn't got your query correctly. you want to check store is empty or products is empty?

Comment: if it worked..please don't forget to rate the answer :)